# c++11 Async seg fault

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, c++11

I'm just trying a few of the new C++11 features with GCC 4.7.2, though when I go to run a seg fault occurs.

```
$ ./a.out
Message from main.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Unknown error -1
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I compiled with the 'beta' features of GCC, in regards to c++0x with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 c11.cpp
```

The code:

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

void called_from_async() {
  std::cout << "Async call" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  //called_from_async launched in a separate thread if possible
  std::future<void> result( std::async(called_from_async));

  std::cout << "Message from main." << std::endl;

  //ensure that called_from_async is launched synchronously 
  //if it wasn't already launched
  result.get();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe this happens because you have forgot to link with POSIX threads library. Just add `-pthread` or `-lpthread` to the `g++` flags and the problem should go away.

If you are interested in details, this happens because C++11 runtime is resolving symbols from  `pthread` in run-time only if you happen to use those features. So if you forgot to link, the runtime won't be able to resolve those symbols, treat your environment as if it doesn't support threads, and throw exception (which you don't catch and it aborts your application).